# Kак переменную сделать локальной?

Tags: javascript

Не знаю как переменную `arr` сделать локальной:

```js
let list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
      }
    }
  }
};

let arr = []
let zz = (list) => {
  for (let key of Object.values(list)) {
    if (typeof key != 'object') {
      arr.push(key)
    } else {
      zz(key)
    }
  }
  return arr
}
console.log(zz(list));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
      }
    }
  }
};

let zz = (list) => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let key of Object.values(list)) {
    if (typeof key != 'object') {
      arr.push(key);
    } else {
      arr = arr.concat(zz(key));
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(zz(list));
```

Comment: большое спосибо